# shows token miss match exception in laravel form post

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a simple form to create user registration, but when the form, submit it shows an error "token mismatch exception". I have already tried replacing the name field and id fields but I can't find what's wrong.
can any  one please tell me what's wrong?

```
<form action="http://example.com/registration" method="POST">
...............
......
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is becuase you are not passing the security token along with your form data.
please use

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) }}
   ........
........
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Laravel provides an easy method of protecting your application from cross-site request forgeries. First, a random token is placed in your user's session. If you use the Form::open method with POST, PUT or DELETE the CSRF token will be added to your forms as a hidden field automatically. Alternatively, if you wish to generate the HTML for the hidden CSRF field, you may use the token method:

```
echo Form::token();
```

you can find full documentation in this link http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the CSRF token to your form:

```html
<form action="http://example.com/registration" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    ......
</form>
```

To quote [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-introduction):

> Laravel makes it easy to protect your application from [cross-site request forgeries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). Cross-site request forgeries are a type of malicious exploit whereby unauthorized commands are performed on behalf of the authenticated user.
>
> Laravel automatically generates a CSRF "token" for each active user session managed by the application. This token is used to verify that the authenticated user is the one actually making the requests to the application. To generate a hidden input field `_token` containing the CSRF token, you may use the `csrf_field` helper function